# Checking for exception type in try/catch block in C#

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I have a rather basic question I've been thinking about.

Refer to the following code snippet that uses a **try/catch** block:

```
public void doSomething()  
{  
   try
    {
        doSomethingElse()
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is IndexOutOfRangeException || ex is DivideByZeroException || ex is Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

1) If all I want to do is output the exception message to the console, is it necessary to check in the **if** clause what type of Exception I'm getting, or can I just do

```
...
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
...
```

2) It is my understanding that checking the specific exception type should be used if I need to output a defined message to the console instead of using the exception message itself - something along the lines of

```
...
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        switch (ex):
        {
            case IndexOutOfRangeException:
                Console.WriteLine("Personalized message #1");               
                break;
            case DivideByZeroException:
                Console.WriteLine("Personalized message #2");               
                break;
            case Exception:
                Console.WriteLine("Personalized message #3");               
                break;
        }
    }
...
```

Your comments on 1) and 2) are highly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: `|| ex is Exception` is always going to return true, so the if-statement is kind of useless.

Comment: You don't have to know the type of exception to output its message but a bigger issue is that you should never just swallow exceptions, and I would argue that catching `Exception` is also a big code smell. For logging, ***maybe***, but I would still try to catch the exceptions I know are safe to log.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen would you please clarify the meaning of "swallow exceptions" and "code smell"? (sorry for the dumb question)

Answer (score 8):

> 1) If all I want to do is output the exception message to the console,
>   is it necessary to check in the if clause what type of Exception I'm
>   getting

No there is no need to check each exception type, if you only want to display its message. Simply use `Exception.Message` property.

> 2) it is my understanding that checking the specific exception type
>   should be used if I need to output a defined message to the console
>   instead of using the exception message itself

Rather catching base exception and then comparing each for different type, **catch specific exception first and then base in the end in each catch block**

```
try
{

}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException indexOutOfRangeException)
{
      //Specific handling
}
catch (DivideByZeroException divideByZeroException)
{
      //Specific handling
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      //Exception handling for all other cases
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Point (1) is correct.

Regarding point (2), the `switch` isn't needed. Instead you can do:

```
try
{
    doSomethingElse()
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Personalized message #1");               
}
catch (DivideByZeroException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Personalized message #2");               
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Personalized message #3");               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In exception handling go from the most specific exception to the more generic (thus the Exception is last).

You can even rethrow exceptions from within catch and modify the message if you want

The proper way to do this would be:

```
try{
}catch(IndexOutOfRangeException e){
    LOGGER.errorFormat("This is an error {0}", e.Message);
    LOGGER.debugFormat("More infor on the exception {0}", e.StackTrace);
}catch(DivideByZeroException ex){
    LOGGER.errorFormat("This is an error {0}", ex.Message);
    LOGGER.debugFormat("More infor on the exception {0}", ex.StackTrace);
    throw new Exception("This is custom message");
}...
catch(Exception eex){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If all I want to do is output the exception message to the console, is it necessary to check in the if clause what type of Exception I'm getting, or can I just do

No it isn't necessary, yes you can just do

> It is my understanding that checking the specific exception type should be used if I need to output a defined message to the console instead of using the exception message itself - something along the lines of..

It should be used to handle exceptions in a different way. But more to the point, you should be using `catch` to handle exceptions that you don't expect to come across, not to handle program flow (which is what I imagine you are trying to do with your personalised messages). Instead you should have error handling in place that catches the thing that causes the exception before it ever gets there

instead of

```
catch(IndexOutOfRangeException)
```

use before hand

```
if(currentIndex < something.Length)
     //do my thing
```

If it is from a user input, you can validate `currentIndex` in this situation in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using ex.Message, and instead just using ex.ToString().  As far as I know, that gives you all the information about the exception.